# How do I use a record that has dots stored in it without throwing errors? (In PLSQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have the following loop in a procedure to scramble PII. The issue is that the IV_USER is stored as James.T.Sanders with dots withing the name. This is causing me to get ORA-00904: "James"."T"."Sanders": invalid identifier

Is there a way around this?

```
        OPEN user_list FOR 'select IV_USER FROM EXT_USER.PORTAL_ACCOUNTS';
        LOOP
        FETCH user_list INTO user_list_rec;
            execute immediate 'update EXT_USER.PORTAL_ACCOUNTS set PERSON_ID=:ssan_new WHERE IV_USER='||user_list_rec.IV_USER||' ' USING ssan_new;
            ssan_new := ssan_new + 1;

        END LOOP;
```

If any more clarification is needed please let me know.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using dynamic SQL here?  Neither of your queries appears to need it and using dynamic SQL vastly complicates the problem.

Comment: @Ben - I don't believe it is a duplicate as that is a different error and does not appear to solve my current problem unless you can explain otherwise.

Comment: It is an exact duplicate even though the error is slightly different @Werbel; you're not quoting a string, therefore Oracle believes that James.T.Sanders is an object..

Comment: @Justin Cave - That is the only way I could think of to loop through thousands of lines of users. If there is a better way to do this while still being part of the procedure then  please let me know.

Comment: @Ben - The object is being stored as a VARCHAR as far as I can tell.

        TYPE user_list_rec_type IS RECORD (IV_USER VARCHAR2(100));
        user_list_rec     user_list_rec_type;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the *assignment* in the `WHERE` condition missed *Single* Quotes!

As the Query is framed a String, assigning a VARCHAR variable just paste the value like `WHERE IV_USER = James.T.Sanders`. And it has to be either used as a bind variable or enclosed within single quotes !

```
    OPEN user_list FOR 'select IV_USER FROM EXT_USER.PORTAL_ACCOUNTS';
    LOOP
    FETCH user_list INTO user_list_rec;
        execute immediate 'update EXT_USER.PORTAL_ACCOUNTS set PERSON_ID=:ssan_new WHERE IV_USER='''||user_list_rec.IV_USER||''' ' USING ssan_new;
        ssan_new := ssan_new + 1;

    END LOOP;
```

OR (Without a *Dynamic* SQL for UPDATE, Ofcourse many solutions are possible without dynamic SQL)

```
    OPEN user_list FOR 'select IV_USER FROM EXT_USER.PORTAL_ACCOUNTS';
    LOOP
    FETCH user_list INTO user_list_rec;
        update EXT_USER.PORTAL_ACCOUNTS set PERSON_ID = ssan_new WHERE IV_USER = user_list_rec.IV_USER;
        ssan_new := ssan_new + 1;

    END LOOP;
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. I just kicked off the script and it got past that portion with ease. I will know in a few hours if the script as a whole works.

Thank you for the timely answer.

Comment: Sure, But, it is always advisable to avoid _Dynamic_ SQL, unless there's a compelling reason. Good Luck!